# using readline() and then using it in write() with a message behind it will save to next line

Tags: python

When you readline() from a file and try to write it to another txt file with text behind it the text behind it always goes to the next line, is there any way to not let it go to the next line and just put it behind it?
example code:

```
file = open('directory/whatever/file.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('directory/whatever/file2.txt', 'a')
line = file.readline()
file2.write(line + 'Thiswillprintonthenextline')
```

the message behind it will print on the next line
that's what I want to prevent

Comment: The line you read from the file will end with a newline character (except perhaps if it was the very last line in the file).  You need to strip that off, or otherwise insert your additional text prior to the newline.

Comment: Unrelated, but you must take care of closing your files. The  `with` statement is your friend here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file2.write(line.rstrip('\n') + 'Thiswillprintonthenextline')
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the readline() function creates a string with the newline character at the end.
If you want to print it without changing the lines, simply strip the last character:

```
file2.write(line.rstrip("\n") + 'Thiswillprintonthenextline')
```

You could also strip it immediately when reading, so you don't have to do it every time you want to print it...
Just replace the line

```
line = file.readline()
```

with the line

```
line = file.readline().rstrip("\n")
```

and you're done. ;)

(Thanks to [bruno desthuilliers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41316/bruno-desthuilliers) for suggesting rstrip.)

Comment: you may want to use `line.rstrip("\n")` instead

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You're of course absolutely right. Wasn't thinking there..